# Accessing a functional component state from another functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-functional-component

The program I am writing tells the user their astrological sign based on their birthday (user input from select elements). I use a router to switch between three pages: Home, Quiz, and Result. Those three components are stored in a Pages folder within the src. **Quiz contains CalcSign, the component that calculates the person's sign. signState is a state within the Quiz component. I want to display signState on the Result page** and potentially use it in future comparison statements within Result. Currently, signState does not display on the Result page. 

Thanks

**Quiz.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

function Quiz () {
  const [monthState, setMonth] = useState("");
  const [dayState, setDay] = useState("");
  const [signState, setSign] = useState("");
let navigate = useNavigate();

function CalcSign() 
{
  if((monthState == 'mar' && dayState > 20)|| (monthState == 'apr' && dayState <= 19))
  {
    setSign("Aries");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'apr' && dayState > 19)|| (monthState == 'may' && dayState <= 20))
  {
    setSign("Taurus");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'may' && dayState > 20)|| (monthState == 'jun' && dayState <= 20))
  {
    setSign("Gemini");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'jun' && dayState > 20)|| (monthState == 'jul' && dayState <= 22))
  {
    setSign("Cancer");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'jul' && dayState > 22)|| (monthState == 'aug' && dayState <= 22))
  {
    setSign("Leo");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'aug' && dayState > 22)|| (monthState == 'sep' && dayState <= 22))
  {
    setSign("Virgo");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'sep' && dayState > 22)|| (monthState == 'oct' && dayState <= 22))
  {
    setSign("Libra");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'oct' && dayState > 22)|| (monthState == 'nov' && dayState <= 21))
  {
    setSign("Scorpio");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'nov' && dayState > 21)|| (monthState == 'dec' && dayState <= 21))
  {
    setSign("Sagitarius");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'dec' && dayState > 21) || (monthState == 'jan' && dayState <= 19))
    {
      setSign("capricorn");
      return (<> </>);
    
    }
  else if((monthState == 'jan' && dayState > 19)|| (monthState == 'feb' && dayState <= 18))
  {
    setSign("Aquarius");
    return (<> </>);
  }
  else if((monthState == 'feb' && dayState > 18)|| (monthState == 'mar' && dayState <= 20))
  {
    setSign("Pisces");
    return (<> </>);
  }

    else
    {setSign("not");
       return (<p>You didn't enter your birthday correctly</p>);}  
  }
  
return (
    <div>
    <label for="quiz">Please select your birthday</label>
<select name="month" id="month" onChange = {(e) => 
  {const selectedMonth = e.target.value;
   setMonth(selectedMonth);}}>  

  <option value="defaultMonth">Birth month</option>
  <option value="jan">January</option>
  <option value="feb">February</option>
  <option value="mar">March</option>
  <option value="apr">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="jun">June</option>
  <option value="jul">July</option>
  <option value="aug">August</option>
  <option value="sep">September</option>
  <option value="oct">October</option>
  <option value="nov">November</option>
  <option value="dec">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day" id="day" onChange = {(e) => 
  {const selectedDay = e.target.value;
   setDay(selectedDay);}}>

  <option value="defaultDay">select a day</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<CalcSign/> 
        <button type = "button" onClick = {() => {navigate("/result");}} >What's my sign</button>
        {dayState} //show that the assignment works properly
        {signState} //show that the assignment works properly
    </div>
  );
}
export default Quiz;
```

**Result.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Quiz from "./Quiz";

function Result() {
 const displaySign = (props) => {
    return (<p>{props.signState} </p>)
  } 
 

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Your result is </h2> 
        <div> {displaySign(<Quiz/>)}</div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default Result;
```

I also tried `<p> {signState} </p>` and `<p><Quiz signState/> </p>` under the `<h2> Your result is </h2>`

Comment: where did you pass the prop?

Comment: You seem to have fundamentally misunderstood how React is supposed to be used. There's no point at all in CalcSign being a component, it could be a pure (and therefore easily tested) function mapping from month and day to sign, without _any_ React in it. Also you should look into how to use _loops_ or _arrays_ to render multiple similar things with less repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address simply your need to pass some values through the route transition to the `"/result"` page, pass the `signState` state in route state.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

This is the `useNavigate` and `navigate` function type defintions.

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

When calling `navigate` to issue an imperative navigation, use the second argument, `options`, to send route state.

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    navigate(
      "/result",                // <-- `to` arg
      { state: { signState } }, // <-- `options` arg
    );
  }}
>
  What's my sign
</button>
```

Access the route state on the receiving component via the `location` object.

[useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation)

> ```
> declare function useLocation(): Location;
>
> interface Location<S extends State = object | null>
>   extends Path {
>   state: S;
>   key: Key;
> }
> ```

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Result() {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Your result is </h2> 
      <div>
        <p>{state.signState}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you sharing this thorough recommendation. In order to implement this properly would I need to use TypeScript? Is there a way to do it in javaScript?

Comment: @MelCodes Oh, sorry if the Typescript is throwing you off, that's just how `react-router` implements the package, I was only quoting the interfaces from the official docs. You don't need to use Typescript to use `react-router-dom` at all. If you notice, my suggested code is vanilla Javascript React code.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. I think I am understanding your approach. I am stuck on two parts. I'll ask them individually:

`declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;

interface NavigateFunction {
  (
    to: To,
    options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
  ): void;
  (delta: number): void;
}`
Does my declaration `let navigate = useNavigate();` not accomplish what is proposed by you here? If not do you mind helping me understand this? The type annotation is new to me, and I don't really know how I would write this.

Comment: @MelCodes I'm just sharing the `navigate` function's interface from the docs, it tells you what arguments and their shapes `navigate` takes, i.e. what you can pass to it. I'm pointing out that `navigate` takes 2 arguments, the second of which is an `options` object that has two properties, `replace` and `state`. Pass any value you need on the `state` property of the `options` object passed as the second argument.

Comment: thank you; I appreciate your tactful and constructive feedback. Just wondering if you had any quick comments on the CalcSign functional component. I wanted to make it just a function, but couldn't figure it out. I think this relates to the way I used if else statements; I only really see them being used for conditional rendering (I am a Java dev learning React). Asking here because I don't have access to start a chat yet.

Comment: @MelCodes Well, generally don't declare React components inside other React components, this is anti-pattern. You are abusing scope/enclosure of the `Quiz` component's state updater functions. Seems to me all the logic you've baked into `CalcSign` would be code executed in a React component lifecycle, i.e. in an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state values the select inputs are updating, i.e. `monthState` and `dayState`. There's also potential render looping issue when you unconditionally update state in `CalcSign` as an unintentional side-effect in `Quiz`'s render return.

Comment: to automate the code more, would you recommend using a for loop to fill an array with all possible numbers (days in a month), then use the map function to map the values to select options? Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: @MelCodes Yes? To make the days selection more ***DRY*** you could create an array of 1 through 31 and map, something like `Array.from({ length: 31 }, (_, i) => i + 1).map(day => <option key={day} value={day}>{day}</option>)`. [array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a state object with your `navigate('/result')` call. In other words, change that line to `onClick = {() => navigate('/result', { signState })}`. In your Result component, you *may* need to call the `useLocation` hook to read the state if it's not a direct Route.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Quiz from "./Quiz";

function Result() {
 const location = useLocation();
 const { signState } = location.state;
 

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Your result is </h2> 
        <div>{signState}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Result;
```